# Configuration of points on a plane curve

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, projective-geometry, curves, enumerative-geometry

Let $C\subset\mathbb{P}^2$ be a smooth plane curve of degree six. On $C$ there are $21$ points given as the intersection points of two lines choosen among a set of seven lines. More precisely there are distinct lines $L_1,\dots,L_7$ such that $p_{i,j} = L_i\cap L_j \in C$ for all $i,j = 1,\dots,7$.

Does anyone know if these $21$ points have a special meaning from the point of view of $C$? And if so can they be recovered from the equation of $C$?

Comment: Relevant: https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/2011-139-12/S0002-9939-2011-11204-8/S0002-9939-2011-11204-8.pdf. The configuration of points is called a “star configuration”. I’ll try to write more later.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A set of points in the plane is called a star configuration of type $\ell$ if it is the set of pairwise intersections of some $\ell$ lines, no three concurrent. If the lines are defined by $L_1,\dotsc,L_\ell$, it's clear that each product $\hat{L}_j = L_1 \dotsm \widehat{L_j} \dotsm L_\ell = (\prod L_i)/L_j$ vanishes on the set of points $X$. In fact, these generate the ideal of $X$, $I_X = (\hat{L}_1,\dotsc,\hat{L}_\ell)$.

A star configuration $X$ lies on a curve $C$ defined by $F$ if and only if $F \in I_X$. In the case you are asking about, a star configuration of type $7$ lying on a sextic curve, $F$ has the same degree as all the $\hat{L}_j$, so they correspond to an expression $F = a_1 \hat{L}_1 + \dotsb + a_7 \hat{L}_7$, for some constants $a_1,\dotsc,a_7$.

Starting from $X$ there's evidently a family of sextics containing $X$. Conversely, a general sextic $C$ contains no such star configuration, by counting constants (the dimension of the space of sextics is way bigger than the dimension of the space of star configurations). For more see [Carlini-Van Tuyl](https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/2011-139-12/S0002-9939-2011-11204-8/S0002-9939-2011-11204-8.pdf).

It seems reasonable to guess that if a sextic $C$ contains a star configuration of type $7$, then that star configuration should be unique. But that fails for some cases, e.g., if $F = L_1 \dotsm L_6$ is a product of $6$ general lines (then $F$ contains a family of star configurations given by any general choice of a seventh line $L_7$). Perhaps it holds for all irreducible $C$ or all smooth $C$, but I don't know.

But there's at least a partial answer to your second question: from the equation $F$ of $C$, if you can write $F$ as a sum of products of $6$ linear forms, drawn from the same set of $7$ linear forms, then it recovers a star configuration contained in $C$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Do you know if it is possible to construct a curve $C'$ containing the same star configuration of $C$ without knowing the star configuration explicitly?

Comment: No, I don't know. Writing a polynomial as a sum of products of linear forms is called a Chow decomposition (or other similar names), and in this case it is a sort of special, restricted Chow decomposition (where each term is the product of 6 out of 7 forms). I don't know the results on uniqueness ("identifiability") of Chow decompositions in general, or these special ones.